# ASP.NET Server Control Property Attribute must be required

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols, asp.net-controls

I have a custom ASP.NET server control `CustomControl` with a property attribute `Path`.

If the `Path` is not explicitly specified, then I want an exception to be thrown.

For example,

`<myControls:CustomControl Path="somedirectory/someotherdirectory/somefile.ext" runat="server" />`

should compile, and

`<myControls:CustomControl runat="server" />` should throw an exception.

I realize I can do this in the getter of the `Path` property, but is there some attribute that necessitates this?

### Update

Is there any mechanism for validating the values of the property attributes other than using in the getter methods of the code-behind properties?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flag control properties as required in design view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787473/flag-control-properties-as-required-in-design-view)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check this in init event of the custom control, and throw an exception.

**Update**

There is; Check it in init event. As init of control's called after host's (page or user control) init event. So you can throw an exception if its null or empty

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this should be a compile time check.

After all, the property value might be supplied in the code behind during page_load or a similiar event.

Comment: for my use case this is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

There is not an attribute that necessitates this.  The best place to do this is in the getter of the Path property.

Comment: You could always write your own attribute though

Comment: Writing attributes doesn't do much good if nothing processes them.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to force the page framework to do this. You need to do it in your code at runtime and raise an exception if the value wasn't provided. Otherwise we'd never run into the "crap, I forgot the runat=server part" error :)